# Excluding common words from a text file in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new at scripting in powershell and I am trying to create a code that will display the top 20 words in a text file(poem.txt), but will also exclude common words such as "and", "if", "a". I was able to finally get to filter the list but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to exclude common words. Any help would be great.

`"poem.txt"`

```
$contents = Get-Content -Path $file
$words = $contents.split(" .,?()") | Where-Object {$_} 
$words | Group-Object | Where-Object Count -GE 20 | sort-object count -descending |% {$_.split(" ")} |? {$_ -notin "and", "if, "a"}
```

Comment: See `foreach -?` and check out `.replace`

Comment: try `foreach($line in $contents){$line.replace("and","").replace("if","").replace("etc.","") >> NewFile.txt}`

Answer (score 1):

You syntax is correct, the order of executions piped is wrong. And no need to do |% {$_.split(" ")}. Your code works like this:

```
$words |? {$_ -notin "and", "if", "the"} | Group-Object | Where-Object Count -ge 20 | sort-object count -descending
```

where-object {$_ -notin "and", "if", "a"} works on piped array $words but will not piped Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupInfo Group-Object